# Call Twitter script when Div is visible

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, dom-events, visibility

On my page, there is a script that calls Twitter like this:

The initial visibility for this div is hidden.

```
<div class="YGNH DSL" id="twitter_update_list">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tweetsv3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/WebMasterAmy.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1">
    </script>
</div>
```

All the js is twitters, but right now, twitter is called when the page loads and it's making the page load slow, so I want to make it to where the Script is called only when `<div class="YGNH DSL" id="twitter_update_list">` is visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, you can do something like

```
function toggleTwitterDiv() {
    var div = $('#twitter_update_list');
    div.toggle(function() {
        if (div.is(':visible')) {
            //make twitter call here
        }
    })
}

toggleTwitterDiv();
```

Comment: Do I put that in the js file, or in the head section of the page, or add it to the script in the div?

Comment: if you're using jquery, you can put it anywhere you want after you've loaded jquery. you need to wire this up to an event handler of some sort, as i assume you'll be clicking something to toggle this div's visibility

Comment: I cant seem to get it figured out because that second line of script is calling twitter onload, and the event is clicking another div container.  If I move that second line of code, then the text doesn't display in the div i want it to.  You can have a look at the site: [link](http://www.purpledragonwebdevelopment.com)  clicking the dragon tail div shows the tweet div.  Thank you for your help.